# How to automate a browsing task?

Tags: php, python, perl, curl, selenium

For weeks I am  trying to automate a browsing task.
The task is simple: **login, click links, enter variable and submit, logout**.
I need to create a website that does this (Sort of a simpler interface) Bare in mind the website is using Servlets and I do not have access to website codes.
At first I tried CURL, but since there were some Ajax Elements in the page curl was not able to show that content.
I tried .NET Webdriver, JUnit, Selenium, etc. But All have failed on rendering ajax elements.
I've tried perl and python mechanize, while perl did not work, I was able to get the dynamic content with python. 
The problem is not that I have links that are Javascript executions they start with Javascript:  and I don't think I can call functions with Mechanize.
Does anybody know if this task is even possible?

Comment: Did you try using selenium `waitFor`s to get Ajax to play nice?  How exactly did it 'fail'?

Comment: Selenium failed on Logging in . I used selenium's .NET wrapper and was not able to get past the login screen. I got a "You have to enter password" error. (yes the names for form fields were correct)

Comment: The [Mechanize FAQ](http://p3rl.org/WWW::Mechanize::FAQ#JavaScript) contains work-around for the lack of Javascript support and lists many modules that do have Javascript support.

Comment: I've already tried all and failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Perl module [`WWW::Mechanize`](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize) is the most popular way of automating web-browsing tasks like, downloads, uploads, form submissions, authentication, simple browsing, screen scraping etc. etc.

In case the website contains Javascript, the popular Perl module to handle them is to use [`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox).

So far, "almost" any kind of website including technologies like JavaScript, and Ajax and using SSL security, and or access via proxy server can be handled by a combination of Perl module methods belonging to [`LWP::UserAgent`](http://p3rl.org/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent) and `WWW::Mechanize` or `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`. Loads of example available over the web.

Comment: The way I understand it WWW::Mechanize::Firefox requires MozlRepl which is a firefox extension and has nothing to do with my command line environment.

Comment: What kind of "command line environment" are you using? You can use WWW::Scripter to handle javascript as well.

Comment: Thanks Annjawn, Just linux, The thing is I'm trying to create a website that takes a credential and will run a script to automate some tasks, therefore all the tasks should be done in the script, I will look at Scripter too. But I'm kinda coming to the conclusion that despite what everyone is saying, Handling complex websites with scripts is if possible extremely difficult and module dependent.

Comment: Yes, that's true. There are multiple ways of creating dynamic objects in webpages and each of them has their own properties, handling all of these kinds using a standard module is difficult. There are a bunch of other modules you can have a look but almost all of them require a web browser plugin.

Answer (score 1):

An example using casperjs:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
   verbose: true,
   logLevel: 'debug'
});
casper.start(
   'http://example.com',
   function() {
       this.evaluate( function() {
           return $('#someElementId div').length; // This runs as if it was on the page
       });
       this.fill(
           '#formId',
           {
               email: 'username@example.com',
               password: 'password123'
           },
           true
       ); // This submits login form
   }
);
```

Casperjs stores cookies, so requests to deeper pages are not going to fail.

See [fill](http://casperjs.org/api.html#casper.fill)() for details about submitting forms.

See [evaluate](http://casperjs.org/api.html#casper.evaluate)() for running js as if it was executed on the page you are testing.

If you want to test AJAX actions - no problem. They are going to run as if the page is running in the browser, you can see the results in the DOM. You can launch them manually using evaluate().

Comment: *OOOOO a bunch of random links!* - any more information would be helpful.

Comment: Selenium WebDriver failed on Ajax elements.

Comment: Plus are you sure I'll be able to run server side javascript with Phantom ?